# Detect when process quits or is being killed due out of memory

Tags: linux, bash

My bash script is running some program in background and with wait command waits for it to stop. But there is a high possibility that the background process will be killed because it takes too much memory. I want my script to react differently for a process that ended up gently and for a killed one. How do I check this condition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure your command signals success (with exit code 0) when it succeeds, and failure (non-zero) when it fails.

When a process is killed with SIGKILL by the OOM killer, signaling failure is automatic. (The shell will consider the exit code of signal terminated processes to be 128 + the signal number, so 128+9=137 for SIGKILL).

You then use the fact that `wait somepid` exits with the same code as the command it waits on in an if statement:

```
yourcommand &
pid=$!
....
if wait $pid
then
    echo "It exited successfully"
else
    echo "It exited with failure"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

usually they shutdown with a signal, try to have some signal hander function to handle unpredictable shutdowns, or worst case have another monitoring process, like a task manager.

did you try anything?

by the way some signals cant be handled, like segmentation faults, **SIGSEGV**

Comment: Yes, I have been trying in a lot of ways (eg. like: instead of "./myapp &" doing it like: "(./myapp && commands_handling_gentle_finish)" that would execute the second command only on gentle finish) but I haven't found a way that would cover both cases. Do you know what signal is sended in my case?

Comment: I can try, however, why is your program taking too much memory?? is it containing a memory leak? and can you change the source code?

Answer (score 0):

Simpler solution is

```
yourcommand

if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "It exited successfully"
else
    echo "It exited with failure, exitcode $?"
fi
```