# How to execute a script when Chrome is closed?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to make a timestamped backup of the bookmarks with rsync everytime Chrome exits. How to trigger a script execution right after Chrome closes?

Edit:

This is the default execution script to start Chrome on Linux Mint with the solution I'm trying to implement:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Copyright (c) 2011 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
# Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
# found in the LICENSE file.

# Let the wrapped binary know that it has been run through the wrapper.
export CHROME_WRAPPER="`readlink -f "$0"`"

HERE="`dirname "$CHROME_WRAPPER"`"


"/opt/google/chrome/chrome" & pid=$!

wait $pid

if ! pgrep chrome > /dev/null; then
  echo "It exited successfully"
fi


# Check if the CPU supports SSE2. If not, try to pop up a dialog to explain the
# problem and exit. Otherwise the browser will just crash with a SIGILL.
# http://crbug.com/348761
grep ^flags /proc/cpuinfo|grep -qs sse2
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
  SSE2_DEPRECATION_MSG="This computer can no longer run Google Chrome because \
its hardware is no longer supported."
  if which zenity &> /dev/null; then
    zenity --warning --text="$SSE2_DEPRECATION_MSG"
  elif which gmessage &> /dev/null; then
    gmessage "$SSE2_DEPRECATION_MSG"
  elif which xmessage &> /dev/null; then
    xmessage "$SSE2_DEPRECATION_MSG"
  else
    echo "$SSE2_DEPRECATION_MSG" 1>&2
  fi
  exit 1
fi

# We include some xdg utilities next to the binary, and we want to prefer them
# over the system versions when we know the system versions are very old. We
# detect whether the system xdg utilities are sufficiently new to be likely to
# work for us by looking for xdg-settings. If we find it, we leave $PATH alone,
# so that the system xdg utilities (including any distro patches) will be used.
if ! which xdg-settings &> /dev/null; then
  # Old xdg utilities. Prepend $HERE to $PATH to use ours instead.
  export PATH="$HERE:$PATH"
else
  # Use system xdg utilities. But first create mimeapps.list if it doesn't
  # exist; some systems have bugs in xdg-mime that make it fail without it.
  xdg_app_dir="${XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME/.local/share/applications}"
  mkdir -p "$xdg_app_dir"
  [ -f "$xdg_app_dir/mimeapps.list" ] || touch "$xdg_app_dir/mimeapps.list"
fi

# Always use our versions of ffmpeg libs.
# This also makes RPMs find the compatibly-named library symlinks.
if [[ -n "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" ]]; then
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HERE:$HERE/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
else
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HERE:$HERE/lib"
fi
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

export CHROME_VERSION_EXTRA="stable"

# We don't want bug-buddy intercepting our crashes. http://crbug.com/24120
export GNOME_DISABLE_CRASH_DIALOG=SET_BY_GOOGLE_CHROME

# Automagically migrate user data directory.
# TODO(phajdan.jr): Remove along with migration code in the browser for M33.
if [[ -n "" ]]; then
  if [[ ! -d "" ]]; then
    "$HERE/chrome" "--migrate-data-dir-for-sxs=" \
      --enable-logging=stderr --log-level=0
  fi
fi

# Sanitize std{in,out,err} because they'll be shared with untrusted child
# processes (http://crbug.com/376567).
exec < /dev/null
exec > >(exec cat)
exec 2> >(exec cat >&2)

# Make sure that the profile directory specified in the environment, if any,
# overrides the default.
if [[ -n "$CHROME_USER_DATA_DIR" ]]; then
  # Note: exec -a below is a bashism.
  exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  \
    --user-data-dir="$CHROME_USER_DATA_DIR" "$@"
else
  exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  "$@"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

What OS are you using? In OS X, this shell script will start Chrome and then `do stuff` when Chrome quits - it should be easy to adapt it for your needs in any Unix-like OS.

```
#! /usr/bin/env sh

"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" & pid=$!

wait $pid

if ! pgrep Chrome > /dev/null; then     # no instances of Chrome are running
  # do stuff
fi
```

(based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17800665/4070984))

Edit: And this works for me in Ubuntu:

```
#! /usr/bin/env sh

/opt/google/chrome/chrome & pid=$!

wait $pid

if ! pgrep chrome > /dev/null; then
  # do stuff
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for you help! I'm using Linux Mint fortunately. I tried to apply your solution in the default execution script /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome, but I can't make it work.

Comment: I tried:

"/opt/google/chrome/chrome" & pid=$!

wait $pid

if ! pgrep chrome > /dev/null; then
  echo "It exited successfully"
fi

Comment: What happens - does the message print immediately, or never?

Comment: What's the output of `pgrep Chrome` after you quit Chrome? Does the message print if you remove the `if... fi` condition - and if so, does it happen immediately, or only after you quit Chrome?

Comment: The output of "pgrep chrome" is empty after I quit Chrome. The message without the condition only prints if I put the code at the beginning of the script.

Comment: And if I include the lines: "/opt/google/chrome/chrome" & pid=$! wait $pid (at the beginning of the script alongside the successful echo command), Chrome restarts once instead of closing, and I have to close Chrome again.

Comment: Can you post the exact test of the script you're trying (as an edit to your question if it won't it in a comment)? I've edited my answer with a version that works for me on Ubuntu (if you replace `# do stuff` with `printf "done\n"`), so it should work on Mint too.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way Google Chrome uses processes, monitoring (PID) the process of a specific Google Chrome window (or instance) of it is usually a headache or (almost) impossible.

But, there is a workaround way that makes this possible. Just use the `--user-data-dir` parameter pointing to the `/tmp` folder (`--user-data-dir=/tmp`).

Below, to illustrate, I've created a bash script that starts the http Web service [Gitea](https://gitea.io/en-us/), opens it in a Google Chrome, and then terminates it when the Google Chrome window is closed.

```
#!/bin/bash

gitea & GITEA_PID=$!
sleep 3
google-chrome-stable --user-data-dir=/tmp --app=http://0.0.0.0:3000/ & CHROME_PID=$!
wait $CHROME_PID
kill -9 $GITEA_PID
```

Basically I'm using your same idea. Just adapt.

[Ref(s).: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75013043/3223785 ,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35294908/3223785 ,
https://www.ghacks.net/2013/10/06/list-useful-google-chrome-command-line-switches/ ,
https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/w61dwi/how_do_i_start_firefox_in_a_single_window_with/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3 , ]